# Java Lambda Exception Handling

Tags: java, exception, lambda

I have a problem with the handling of exceptions, without the use of try and catch, in lambdas.

I found example code for which I need to make my own `Consumer` interface, but it doesn't work and I don't know how to fix it.

```
import java.util.function.Consumer;

@FunctionalInterface
public interface ThrowingConsumer<T, E extends Exception> {
    void accept(T t) throws E;

    static <T> Consumer<T> throwingConsumerWrapper(
            ThrowingConsumer<T, Exception> throwingConsumer) {

        return i -> {
            try {
                throwingConsumer.accept(i);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                throw new RuntimeException(ex);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Here is the lambda in which I need to handle `IOException`. This exception must be thrown from main. I do not wish to use try and catch in `main`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Function<String, List<String>> flines = fileName -> {
        Scanner scanner;
        ArrayList<String> wiersze = new ArrayList<>();
        File f = new File(fileName);

        scanner = new Scanner(f); // here :(

        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            wiersze.add(scanner.nextLine());
        }

        scanner.close();

        return wiersze;
    };
}
```

I am new to Java, so please could you explain to me how to fix this problem in the easiest way.

Comment: You can't handle an exception without `catch`ing it.

Comment: why can't you use `try` and `catch`?

Comment: My profesor said that i must do it another way :/

Answer (score 0):

So is your problem that you have a piece of code that throws a checked exception, and you want that to become the implementation of a `Function` object? You've found somewhere how to do it for `Consumer`, you just need the code adapter for `Function`?

Assuming that the rewrite should look something like:

```
import java.util.function.Function;

@FunctionalInterface
public interface ThrowingFunction<T, R, EXC extends Exception> {
    R apply(T t) throws EXC;

    static <T> Function<T> throwingFunctionWrapper(
       ThrowingFunction<T, R, Exception> throwingFunction
    ) {
        return t -> {
            try {
                return throwingFunction.apply(t);
            } catch (Exception exc) {
                throw new RuntimeException(exc);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

To be a little more general, `throwingFunctionWrapper` could be:

```
static <T> Function<T> throwingFunctionWrapper(
   ThrowingFunction<T, R, ? extends Exception> throwingFunction
) {
```

In order to deal with the exception you should subclass `RuntimeException` and then only catch that class, so as to not unwrap any other runtime exceptions.

Unwrap (with the original code) as:

```
try {
   ...
} catch (RuntimeException exc) { // subclass me !!
   throw (IOException)exc.getCause();
}
```